# How should I present 100+ client logos on a website?

Tags: usability

I have more than 100+ client's logos to show on the website. Would it be good to show 5-10 clients on the home page and direct users to the main client page if s/he wants to see more? I say this because lots of data makes page heavy and I'm sure nobody wants to see all the clients on the home page.

My manager is not happy with the idea. He says that all the clients should go in one page in carousal.

I need some logical reasoning to give weight to my suggestion. Whats your thought community?

Comment: I go with the questions to management. does your customers contract authorise your company to display their logo on the website ? (many big company denied that usage without proper documents) What sorting of company do you choose ? alphabetical, size of business, popularity of brand name...

Comment: [Stackexchange](http://stackexchange.com/) has over 100 Q&A pages. Might worth to check how they present them.

Comment: obligatory [xkcd reference](http://xkcd.com/1264/)

Answer (score 9):

Putting lots of standalone logos on the home page is not that effective because it doesn't really convey a message - and certainly not one that makes it worthy of the important home page space. It's more about ego than good business and effective communication.

Nevertheless, it can be important in a B2B environment to be able to show to people that you've worked with their peers in the industry as it immediately shows a level of standing, capability and credibility and that may be important to the types of visitors in your target audience.

An example that I think works well is [webcredible.com](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/)

OK - so yes they use a dreaded carousel and the carousel doesn't pause on hover, but nevertheless if you're planning on using a carousel, this is a reasonable take on it.

Webcredible have a number of case studies in different industries so they can populate the carousel with a meaningful message (and decent photography) and a link to more than just a bunch of logos.

[image]

Then when visitors click to find out out about more case studies, they have a dedicated page for this. But even here - they don't just show a bunch of logos - they let you choose by industry. This is so much nicer than showing a page of logos and making visitors search for businesses that are industry peers in some way. It shows that you've actually thought about the B2B type of visitors to the site and realise that they are most likely to have an interest in their own industry.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to see from your manager point of view. Displaying all the satisfied customer's company logo is very much like medals from serving the army or trophies from all the hunting. They do not require and not designed for user to client to access their page even if it's capable to.

My take will be splash screen of all the logos in the page, placing emphasis on popular company with a larger icon.
If it take a little longer to load, make sure you lower the icon file size.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well carousal is a poor way to present content on the home page, but you could consider to use this pattern if you present eye candy content, e.g. clothes, books. Maybe you could provide on home page only information about industries the company works for and one or two logos for each industry with a link redirecting to the page with all logos divided on the industries.

- http://www.widerfunnel.com/conversion-rate-optimization/rotating-offers-the-scourge-of-home-page-design
- http://shouldiuseacarousel.com

Answer (score 1):

I think some client's names are more persuasive over others (Microsoft vs. Zizu, etc.), so you could place your top clients on home page to get more trust for your product.

To support your point, you can:

- perform [competitive analysis](http://www.inc.com/guides/2010/05/conducting-competitive-research.html)
- provide some points on [carousel effectiveness](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/are-carousels-effective)
- provide [effective carousels rules and cases](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/designing-effective-carousels/?utm_source=Alertbox&utm_campaign=79cab12e06-Alertbox_email_09_16_2013&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_7f29a2b335-79cab12e06-24379097) – it's just boring to watch any logos!

Answer (score 1):

Someone else made an important copyright point:

- Do they have written permission from their client to publish the logo on the site? 
  I worked for IBM, and one of our suppliers had used our logo on their site while not having permission. We asked him to take it down and he did. It could easily have been uglier than that, given there were NDAs involved. So you do need to ask.

As for how to show 100 logos.

Presentation ideas:
- Grid on a separate single page 
- Teaser grid & option to see more 
- Paginated in a frame which fits on the margins of your main page
- Stock ticker style, have them roll through. (I don't like this idea, not a fan of motion on a page unless triggered by the user)
- As watermarks <- Something I saw recently. Use the logo as a watermark behind something else, just on the edge of the page. So logos would be clickable when hovered over, but not in the way otherwise. As there are a lot, consider a "zoom" where the mouse hovers.
- Use [parallax scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling) to fit your 100 logos in a sidebar of 1/4 of the height. Have them scroll through much faster than the main content. This should attract attention as well.

As for giving weight to your argument
- Load times: Yslow
- Competitor analysis (has been mentioned, i know) See how others in same and other industries do this, and discuss what is pleasant or unpleasant about each approach. 
- Standardised methods: check WordPress plugins and other ready-made tools to showcase clients, portfolios, etc...

But the biggest question I would have is. Are they shortcuts to case studies and work examples for each client, or just a boyscout collection of badges? This will factor in to how you'll want to display them. Links need to be clickable, and have some information like a project title. A boyscout badge collection, is just a photowall.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on who do you make your website for (who is your customer). If your site is focused on visitors, then you should do what visitors need. But if your real customer is your manager, CEO, shareholders (it is possible), do what they want.

Comment: But that means you're little more than a robot. People in UX should realize that they're employed not just to deliver specifications that the clients think they want, but to advise and provide expert opinions on what to do. Otherwise all we're doing is just glorified colouring-in.