# Three carousels side by side on the home page, bad idea?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, homepage, carousel, product-placement

My client wants to build an e-commerce website where he wants to display his products(clothing items) on carousels.He is asking me to add three carousels side by side as shown in the drawing in the image below.
[image: drawing]

He says it will be easier for him to design three smaller images than a larger image for the current big carousel. He wants each carousel to represent a category(like t-shirts,sweatshirts,etc.)I think it's a bad idea because, firstly, the users can get frustrated with three separate carousels and never even use that part of the site. Secondly, making three separate carousels sticking together as a responsive design would be a nightmare. Thirdly, according to me(and I can be wrong) it kind of defeats the purpose of a carousel, which would be to showcase the important products and events of the website while promoting them. How do I convince my client that three sliders side by side is a bad idea? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Can we get some more context here? What are the sliders used for? Why does the client want them grouped this way? Why do you think it is a bad idea?

Comment: As JonW said it is contextual, here is Yahoo carousel that I feel can be a good fit for your case: http://prntscr.com/5rdxhw

Comment: Well, it's an ecommerce website so he wants to display his products on the slider. He wants it this way because he says it will be difficult to design the images for a larger carousel but easier for three smaller ones, so he wants to keep three carousels for thres different categories. I think it's a bad idea because, firstly, this way the users can get frustrated with the three sliders and never even use that part of the site. Secondly, making that responsive would be a nightmare. Thirdly, according to me(and I can be wrong) it kind of defeats the purpose of a slider,

Comment: Which would be to showcase the important products and events of the website while promoting them.

Comment: Ok, your description of a slider is not what I would describe as one. Can you provide a mockup example? We don't want people leaving answers that don't relate to your issue, which is likely to happen without more detail. Please [edit] your question to add such detail and examples.

Comment: What would be your description of a slider? And I apologize for the inconvenience. I'm new to stackexchange and I'm still grasping how things work. And, I couldn't add a mockup so I added an image of a drawing instead, hope that would explain things better.Please, do tell if I need to add more details to the question.Thank you for helping out.

Comment: I would think of sliders as these: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/multiple-vertical.html

Comment: Well, you are correct. Let me replace that with carousel to make the question more clear.

Comment: Carousels are typically associated with adds/promos. Not really 'main content'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having 3 sliders is not a bad idea here. Having a single big slider is!
Whenever someone comes to your website to purchase anything, he/she would have a product in mind to buy, the three distinct sliders will nicely
categorize items. So when, I for example am visiting your website to find discounted deals for t-shirts on your website a 
**single carousel will give me general deals of clothing( eh!)**, *my extra clicks would be frustrating in that case*. Since **I won't have any idea of what's next in
the slider**.

Having 3 categories will help me finding deals nicely on t-shirst, not a very good ux but still better than a single Carousel. **Whenever the slider changes, I can expect something relevant**
to appear.

This already existing question will further give more information on carousels: [Are carousels effective?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/are-carousels-effective)

You can discuss with your client on the possibility not using carousel, but if he insists to go with it then I guess you need to provide good
controls for the sliders to the users.

Comment: If the beef is 'extra clicks' than the answer should be 'zero' carousels. Scrolling is much quicker than having to deal with a carousel.

Comment: @DA01 Yes! That's what I have mentioned in my last line. ;-)

Comment: What about new users that visit the website, not knowing what the company is all about, just to get to know the products and the company. Would three carousels be effective for them?

Comment: @DA01 I will try to convince him about not putting up any carousel at all but I just want to know the better alternative in case he is adamant about having a carousel.

Comment: Yes, then it will be far more helpful than a single carousel. Do you have case where a single carousel will be of any help?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to go and test your thesis on usabilityhub. Testing is free if you get enough points by testing others mockups.

Answer (score 3):

Show him this website:
http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/

There are a couple of reasons why he shouldn´t do that.

- 1% clicked a feature. Of those, 89% were the first position. 1% of clicks for the most significant object on the home page?
  nd.edu stats by @erunyon
- “We have tested rotating offers many times and have found it to be a poor way of presenting home page content.”
  wider funnel
- The target was the biggest item on the homepage - the first carousel item. “Nonetheless, the user failed the task.”
  nielsen norman Group
- “Almost all of the testing I’ve managed has proven content delivered via carousels to be missed by users. Few interact with them.”
  adam fellowes
- “Carousels are effective at being able to tell people in Marketing/Senior Management that their latest idea is on the Home Page. Use them to put content that users will ignore on your Home Page. Or, if you prefer, don’t use them. Ever.”
  lee duddell
- “Carousels pose accessibility issues for keyboard and screen reader users that simply cannot be adequately addressed by markup or hacks. Carousels are this decade's `<blink>` tag.”
  jared smith

Comment: Well, I don't think so it's going to help me convince him. I will try though but thank you for this information I'll keep this in mind and try to avoid using carousels

Answer (score 1):

> "[Carousels exist to keep people from beating the $*&# out of each other in meetings.](https://twitter.com/brad_frost/status/393769776457060352)" -- Brad Frost

Problem: The home page isn't big enough to show all the stuff for sale.

Solution: Recommend the top selling item with easy access to the full list.

[image: recommend]

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite catch the point you're trying to make.