# What is the optimal number of images in a carousel so the user can see all of it?

Tags: e-commerce, carousel, speed

I am working on a client's clothing store website. He asked for 7 plus images in the carousel, all with the horizontal transition. He wants to update his product daily with the latest items in the carousel. That means if he is going to update 5 items or maybe 10, he is going to create a mess in the banner portion.

How to deliver the landed user almost all the information? I think too much slider in a carousel is boring and not everyone is going to click the next button and see all the information in the carousel.

If the carousel transition is too quick, the user will miss the information as well when they only wait and see. Even if the transition is up to user readable time, I don't think they will go through all the banner.

What is an effective way to provide the latest updates?

How many images must be in a carousel so that the user can see all of it?

Comment: By banner do you mean a carousel? Just trying to clarify terms

Comment: yes @CharlesWesley

Comment: Obligatory [Should I use a carousel?](http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/)

Comment: Carousel in a real store - https://instagram.com/p/mDnxTxsQA4/ ;)

Comment: Obligatory [Lee Duddell](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/10318/21341).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Q: How many images must be in a carousel so that the user can see all of it?

A: 1

In an [interesting blog post](http://erikrunyon.com/2013/01/carousel-stats/) about carousel interaction stats, [Eric Runyon](https://twitter.com/erunyon) collected data on carousel interactions for various [ND.edu](http://www.nd.edu/) web pages.

What he found is that effectively users only interact with the first item in the carousel:

[image: Static carousels]
[image: Auto-forwarding carousels]

A [concise analysis](https://twitter.com/lukew/status/293857685546360834) of this data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A carousel is an animated content. Therefore, you have to be aware that it will bother the readability of the other informations on the page.

That being said, using a carousel, there is no straight answer to your questions.

The reading time depends of the content complexity. A quite good pattern consists into pausing the animation on mouse over (with a visual feedback of the pause). Of course, the user should be able to play back and forth.

About the number of items, the probability of reading the items decrease with their quantity and complexity. 5 is a usual quantity, related to the cognitive span.

An other option, if many updates are to be provided regularly, is to give up the carousel for a vertical endless scroll...

Answer (score 0):

Carousel should only have 3 or you risk folks missing it.

What about if you create a carousel on the section homepage?

How about just using a product tile gallery homepage.  More eyeballs and easier to switch out