# Are changing titles a good idea?

Tags: conversion, page-title

We are designing the homepage for a B2B website. 
Sales and marketing are asking us to include changing titles on the user's landing. That means the title changes between 6 different titles that tell the user what can be our value to them. We can call those "selling slogans".. Graphic stays the same, only the text changes. 
An example of the behaviour: similarweb.com 
I think message should be generic, spot on the most important message  and fixed. Users won't wait to see what message comes next and the movement is only distracting. 
What do you think? Do you know of any research around this pattern?
Thanks!!

Comment: Could you clarify? Is the "title" the message in the browser window's tab? Or the header on the actual page?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to a carousel, where different visual messages are presented one at a time. Maybe the marketing team got wind that [carousels don't work](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10312/are-carousels-effective?rq=1) so they're moving their slide-show feature into the page title.

The principle is the same, and you summarized it well: "Users won't wait to see what message comes next and the movement is only distracting." My rule of thumb is to not let the Marketing Dept design your site.

[Nielsen/Norman](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/designing-effective-carousels/) have done research on carousels and provide some guidelines if you absolutely must use one.

Answer (score 1):

Using different slogans isn't uncommon, but animating/changing them is. You should have the text be fixed, but it can be randomized on page load. Note; this should only be done with a SUBtitle. So for example;

MoBiCorp,
 Into the future

MoBiCorp,
 Connecting the world

But not as a standalone text.

And you are right about animation, users waiting etc. Users won't want to wait, and even more importantly, they are not aware they should.